# Как добавить отступ текста свехру

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Есть такой стиль:

```css
.help {
  font-size: 120%;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #00FF00;
}

span {
  margin-top:15px;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="help" >
  <span style="text-align: center;">О приложении</span>
</div>
```

Текст упорно лезит верх, не действует, ни `margin-top`, ни `text-align`. И текст "О приложении" прилипает к верху.

Как сделать отступ сверху и слева?

Comment: А может вам просто надо вертикально отцентрировать текст? Для этого существуют другие приёмы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<span>` - строчный элемент. Чтоб появился отступ сверху или снизу, необходимо задать ему `display: block` или `inline-block`.

```css
.help {
  font-size: 120%;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #333366;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #00FF00;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top:15px;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="help" >
  <span style="text-align: center;">О приложении</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Работает, спасибо